# Problema con el input submit

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

Estimados estoy realizando un formulario con un script en el cual al momento de enviarlo el input submit no me quiere enviar el formulario y en cambio en el mismo proyecto pero en otra vista tengo el código similar pero que si me funciona el input y ahí es donde no sé como solucionarlo.

Aquí tengo el formulario

```
<form id="agregarProfesionalForm">
            <div class="row g-3">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h5 class="mb-3">Nombre:</h5>
                    <input name="nombreProf" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h5 class="mb-3"></i>Apellido:</h5>
                    <input name="apPaterProf" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row g-3" style="margin-top: 3px;">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h5 class="mb-3">Rut:</h5>
                    <input name="rutProf" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar Profesional" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 25px; width: 180px; background-color: blueviolet;" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Y aqui el script

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#agregarProfesionalForm").submit(function (e) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    url = "@Url.Content("~/Admin/agregarProfesional")"
                    parametros = $(this).serialize();

                    $.post(url, parametros, function (data) {
                        if (data == "KinesiologoAgregado") {
                            alert("Kinesiologo Ingresado");
                            document.location.href = "@Url.Content("~/Admin/listaUsuariosView")";
                        } else if (data == "NutricionistaAgregado") {
                            alert("Nutricionista Ingresado");
                            document.location.href = "@Url.Content("~/Admin/listaUsuariosView")";
                        } 
                        else {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    })

                })

            })
        </script>
```

Comment: ¿Y la consola que te imprime?

Comment: Hola, es cierto que más información sobre el error que te da ayudaría. Pero así de entrada, a mi me extraña que estés usando "Url.Content" en lugar de "Url.Action" para construir las urls, porque generalmente Url.Content es para construir la url de un recurso o archivo físico (como un jpg o un pdf que tengas en el servidor) y Url.Action para los métodos de los Controladores

Comment: Ese es el problema, no me genera ningún error al realizar la acción solamente cuando presiono el botón de enviar no pasa nada, me deja marcado el botón y nada más y tengo el mismo código con el script similar(obviamente con los parámetros que le corresponden) y esos si me funcionan pero con este me falla